# How can I identify the time offset between two similar BUT MATERIALLY DIFFERENT MP3 files?

Tags: audio, mp3

I have hundreds of pairs of instrumental/vocal MP3 files. The instrumental version has music played with instruments. The vocal version does too, but it also has a vocal track overlaid.

I don't know what all processing went into creating these MP3 files, but I do know that the instrumental and vocal versions often do not have the same length, and they often start with a different length of silence.

I need to figure out what the offset is between each pair of MP3 files. Because there are so many of them, I would prefer a command line solution.

I don't know anything about signal processing, I'm hoping for some existing tool that can easily do this. Any ideas?

Comment: This question is not a dupe of the other. My MP3 files do not have duplicate data. They're materially different.

Comment: Agree not a dupe. @random The other thread is about a search and destroy for dupes, this is for analyzing similar audio files and the contents of those files.

Comment: Then it would be re-closed as a tools request

Comment: @random Where would I direct a tools request then?

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks! http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14954/how-can-i-identify-the-time-offset-between-two-similar-but-materially-different